# When ListView and edittext in a same screen cause a error

Tags: android, listview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <include
        android:id="@+id/action_bar_detail"
        layout="@layout/action_bar" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/linlay_reply"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_detail_reply"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:text="@string/reply" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_reply_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/btn_detail_reply"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:labelFor="@id/et_reply_content" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lv_passage_detail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/linlay_reply"
        android:layout_below="@id/action_bar_detail"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:dividerHeight="2dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

when I close the soft keyboard after fininshing entering the some content in the edittext.

According to the logcat  ,it cause a error like following
1.yesterday was "MessageQueue-JNI"
2.this morning is "Performing stop of activity that is not resumed."

I am so confuse.Can anybody figure it out ?

```
04-11 14:49:10.032: E/libEGL(5593): call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)
04-11 14:49:15.813: E/AndroidRuntime(5593): Process: com.example.simplebbs, PID: 5593
04-11 14:49:15.813: E/AndroidRuntime(5593): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-11 14:49:15.813: E/AndroidRuntime(5593):     at simplebbs.example.adapter.PassageDetailAdapter.getView(PassageDetailAdapter.java:74)
04-11 14:49:15.813: E/AndroidRuntime(5593):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2324)
04-11 14:49:15.813: E/AndroidRuntime(5593):     at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1812)
04-11 14:49:15.813: E/AndroidRuntime(5593):     at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:698)
04-11 14:49:15.813: E/AndroidRuntime(5593):     at android.widget.ListView.fillSpecific(ListView.java:1359)
04-11 14:49:15.813: E/AndroidRuntime(5593):     at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1623)
04-11 14:49:15.813: E/AndroidRuntime(5593):     at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2173)
04-11 14:49:15.813: E/AndroidRuntime(5593):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15128)
04-11 14:49:15.813: E/AndroidRuntime(5593):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4867)
04-11 14:49:15.813: E/AndroidRuntime(5593):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1160)
04-11 14:49:15.813: E/AndroidRuntime(5593):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15128)
04-11 14:49:15.813: E/AndroidRuntime(5593):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4867)
04-11 14:49:15.813: E/AndroidRuntime(5593):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:515)
04-11 14:49:15.813: E/AndroidRuntime(5593):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:450)
04-11 14:49:15.813: E/AndroidRuntime(5593):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15128)
04-11 14:49:15.813: E/AndroidRuntime(5593):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4867)
04-11 14:49:15.813: E/AndroidRuntime(5593):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1888)
04-11 14:49:15.813: E/AndroidRuntime(5593):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1742)
04-11 14:49:15.813: E/AndroidRuntime(5593):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1651)
04-11 14:49:15.813: E/AndroidRuntime(5593):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15128)
04-11 14:49:15.813: E/AndroidRuntime(5593):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4867)
04-11 14:49:15.813: E/AndroidRuntime(5593):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:515)
04-11 14:49:15.813: E/AndroidRuntime(5593):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:450)
04-11 14:49:15.813: E/AndroidRuntime(5593):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15128)
04-11 14:49:15.813: E/AndroidRuntime(5593):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4867)
04-11 14:49:15.813: E/AndroidRuntime(5593):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2321)
04-11 14:49:15.813: E/AndroidRuntime(5593):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2027)
04-11 14:49:15.813: E/AndroidRuntime(5593):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1193)
04-11 14:49:15.813: E/AndroidRuntime(5593):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6230)
04-11 14:49:15.813: E/AndroidRuntime(5593):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:788)
04-11 14:49:15.813: E/AndroidRuntime(5593):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:591)
04-11 14:49:15.813: E/AndroidRuntime(5593):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:560)
04-11 14:49:15.813: E/AndroidRuntime(5593):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:774)
04-11 14:49:15.813: E/AndroidRuntime(5593):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
04-11 14:49:15.813: E/AndroidRuntime(5593):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
04-11 14:49:15.813: E/AndroidRuntime(5593):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
04-11 14:49:15.813: E/AndroidRuntime(5593):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5390)
04-11 14:49:15.813: E/AndroidRuntime(5593):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-11 14:49:15.813: E/AndroidRuntime(5593):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-11 14:49:15.813: E/AndroidRuntime(5593):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:851)
04-11 14:49:15.813: E/AndroidRuntime(5593):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:667)
04-11 14:49:15.813: E/AndroidRuntime(5593):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

now different thing.
When I set the visibility of edittext to gone.The error is gone, too.

```
if (mComments.size() != 0 && position != 0) {
                detailHolder.replyContent.setText(mComments.get(position - 1)
                        .getReplyContent());
                detailHolder.replytime.setText(mComments.get(position - 1)
                        .getReplyTime());
                detailHolder.replyUserName.setText(mComments.get(position - 1)
                        .getReplyUserName());
            }
```

This is the error place where the logcat say.

Comment: Please share some code, its hard to guess what happened without it

Comment: I think the promble is about the Ui thread.But I don't know too much about that

Comment: @Richardchan please can you add your adapter class?

Comment: @Richardchan, have you written  any code for listview to populate

Comment: @Pankaj Nimgade,Yeah,I alreay do that

Comment: @Richardchan, can you post the code as well to debug

Comment: 04-11 15:20:46.346: E/InputEventReceiver(11208): Exception dispatching input event.                 Maybe this is what the question is?? what do you guys think?

Answer (score 0):

There should be no relation between your editbox and listview. If your are trying to get the user input and want to populate in listview then some issue may happen.
What your logcat says that its a nullpointer exception. Means either your textview in which you are trying to load data is null or the object(mComment) is null.

Comment: Exception dispatching input event.     I found this msg in the logcat

Answer (score 0):

I still can't make much of your `listview adapter` without code, so i made something which looks like your layout, let me know, what changes do you have in this for your `listview adapter`.

in this views are more independent than `RelativeLayout` so you should not get the problem with this `layout`

Code

```
private ListView listView;
private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
private String[] menu = { "Example1", "Example1", "Example1", "Example1",
        "Example1", "Example1", "Example1", "Example1", "Example1",
        "Example1", "Example1" };

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.listview_activity);
    listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv_passage_detail);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, menu);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

listview_activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:padding="4dp"
android:background="#eef">



<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:background="#efe"
    android:weightSum="100"
    android:layout_margin="4dp">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" 
        android:layout_weight="70"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:ems="10" 
        android:layout_weight="30">

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

</LinearLayout>

<ListView 
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:id="@+id/lv_passage_detail"
     android:padding="2dp"
     android:layout_margin="4dp"
     android:background="#959"
    />
```

[image: it looks like this]

Comment: @Richardchan, Great, was it the adapter or something else

Comment: @ Pankaj Nimgade,There are two kinds of item in the listview.The reason why the error is dislocation of listview.and because of it ,the data is wrong,too.And I override the "getItemViewType and getitemtypecount" of listview to solve it

Comment: @Richardchan, that's helpful,

Comment: @ Pankaj Nimgade,this is my first to ask a question here.It so kind of you.Again,Thank you.

Comment: As requested by [other user](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41971363/2025923), can you provide complete code here.